# Google Drive Version History -who was "Deleted User"?

Tags: google-api, google-apps

We have a Google Sheets file with version history several years long. Many users in the history are displayed as "Deleted User" Admin Drive Audit can only access 180 days of history so determining the user who made an edit just over 2 years ago is not available. Can Deleted User be determined through GAM or the Drive API? I tried the API explorer and found named user interactions from back then but it didn't list any of the Deleted User info. Any help would be greatly appreciated.